# Intuition for $\mathcal O(1)$ and $\mathcal O(-1)$ on $\mathbf P^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

As a concrete example, consider the space $\mathbf P^2$ over some field $k$ and the embedded $\mathbf A^2\hookrightarrow\mathbf P^2, (x_1, x_2)\mapsto[1:x_1:x_2]$. I want to understand sections of $\mathcal O(1)$ and $\mathcal O(-1)$ on $\mathbf A^2$.

- First, the structure sheaf has sections $\Gamma(\mathcal O, \mathbf A^2)=k[x_0, x_1, x_2]_{(x_0)}=k[\frac{x_1}{x_0}, \frac{x_2}{x_0}]$
- The tautological line bundle has sections $\Gamma(\mathcal O(-1), \mathbf A^2)=(k[x_0, x_1, x_2]_{(x_0)})_(-1)=\frac {1}{x_0} k[\frac{x_1}{x_0}, \frac{x_2}{x_0}]$ as $k[\frac{x_1}{x_0}, \frac{x_2}{x_0}]$-module.

  *Question:* how do I see that this is the same as the more geometric approach, according to which $\mathcal O(-1)$ assigns to a point $[x_0:x_1:x_2]$ the one-dimensional space $k(x_0, x_1, x_2)\subseteq k^3$?
- The twisting sheaf has sections $\Gamma(\mathcal O(1), \mathbf A^2)=(k[x_0, x_1, x_2]_{(x_0)})_1$, which is generated by $x_1, x_2$ as $k[\frac{x_1}{x_0}, \frac{x_2}{x_0}]$-module.

  *Question:* How to I see that that the dual of $\Gamma(\mathcal O(1), \mathbf A^2)$ (as $\Gamma(\mathcal O, \mathbf A^2)$-modules) is $\Gamma(\mathcal O(-1), \mathbf A^2)$?

*My attempt:* For the last question, it somehow sounds reasonable that any monomial $\frac{x_i^n}{x_0^{n+1}}$ gives rise to a morphism $\langle x_1, x_2\rangle\to k[\frac{x_1}{x_0}, \frac{x_2}{x_0}], f\mapsto \frac{x_i^n f}{x_0^{n+1}}$ of $k[\frac{x_1}{x_0}, \frac{x_2}{x_0}]$-modules. Is it clear that this is an isomorphism?

Comment: I don't understant your question $O(1)$ and $O(-1)$ are dual to each other as $O_X$-modules, that is true, but $\Gamma(O(1))$ and $\Gamma(O(-1))$ are not, as $k$-vector spaces. The former is of dimension 3, the latter of dimension 0.

Comment: @A.Rod: I would have thought that $\Gamma(\mathcal H\mathit{om}_\mathcal O(\mathcal F, \mathcal G), U)=\hom_{\mathcal O(U)}(\mathcal F(U), \mathcal G(U))$, and hence that $\Gamma(\mathcal O(-1), U)$ is dual to $\Gamma(\mathcal O(1), U)$ as $\Gamma(\mathcal O, U)$-modules. My question is how to see this duality in the example.

Comment: @A.Rod: After thinking about what I've written, it seems to me that my hom looks wrong. Maybe it should be $\Gamma(\mathcal H\mathit{om}_\mathcal O(\mathcal F, \mathcal G), U)=\hom_{\mathcal O|_U}(\mathcal F|_U, \mathcal G|_U)$. My question still applies.

Comment: Oh, I see you meant over $\mathbb{A}^2$ or any affine open set. I thought you meant the global sections.

Comment: In any case for quasi coherent sheaves the definitions you gave are "almost the same" in the sense that over an affine open subset the sheaf you define in your second comment is the sheaf associated to the module you define in your first.

Comment: Going back to your question, don't you seen any pairing $x_0^{-1}k[x_1/x_0, x_2/x_0]\otimes x_0k[x_1/x_0, x_2/x_0]\to k[x_1/x_0, x_2/x_0]$ which would identify say $x_0k[x_1/x_0, x_2/x_0]$ with $Hom(x_0^{-1}k[x_1/x_0, x_2/x_0], k[x_1/x_0, x_2/x_0])$ that is compatible with localization (of course they're both free modules of rank 1, so such a pairing exists, what you want is a pairing compatible with localization, or "glueing" with the same construction over the other copy of $\mathbb A^2$ if you prefer).

Comment: @A.Rod: i have to admit that the pairing is rather obvious, now that you have pointed me to this. Do you also know an answer to my first question, which was how the line bundle of lines in $k^3$ is seen to be in some way the same as $\mathcal O(-1)$?